# QT main window separate images for horizontal and vertical separators?

Tags: css, qt, stylesheet, separator, qmainwindow

Is it possible to specify separate images for horizontal and vertical separators like we can for `QSplitter`? I tried some of the same css selectors, but no luck. I'm only able to specify the same image for both vertical and horizontal separators as follows:

```
QMainWindow::separator {
    image: url(:icons/splitter_grip_vertical.png);
}
```

I was hoping for something like

```
QMainWindow::separator:horizontal {
    image: url(:icons/splitter_grip_vertical.png);
}

QMainWindow::separator:vertical {
    image: url(:icons/splitter_grip_horizontal.png);
}
```

Is there something undocumented or is this just not possible?

Comment: You looking for right CSS selector or want to set background image to QSplitter Handle?

Comment: I want to use the same "grip" images I use for `QSplitter::handle` for `QMainWindow:separator`, which, in my case, is different for horizontal and vertical orientations as the image is long and thin.